# Update a list in SQL with incremental dates using one statement? 

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am writing an update statement where I need to update a list of items all at once with incremental dates.  The incremental value is user defined.  I found an example that is pretty similar to my needs at http://haacked.com/archive/2004/02/28/sql-auto-increment.aspx , but do not know how I would implement it.  That example is:

```
DECLARE @counter int
SET @counter = 0
UPDATE #tmp_Users
SET @counter = counter = @counter + 1
```

My current statement is:

```
strSQL.CommandText = "Update tblItem set item_timed_close=convert(datetime, @item_timed_close),item_timed_start=convert(money, case when item_est_lo < 500 then ((convert(int,item_est_lo+25)/50)*50) when item_est_lo < 1000 then ((convert(int,item_est_lo+50)/100)*100) when item_est_lo < 3000 then ((convert(int,item_est_lo+125)/250)*250) when item_est_lo < 5000 then ((convert(int,item_est_lo+250)/500)*500) else ((convert(int,item_est_lo+12.5)/25)*25) end ) Where item_sale_id=@item_sale_id";
  strSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@item_timed_close", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "item_timed_close", DataRowVersion.Current, datetime_Var.AddMinutes(minutes_Var += Increments_var)));
  strSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@item_sale_id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "item_sale_id", DataRowVersion.Current, itemSaleId3_Var));
```

datetime_Var is user defined, and is a `DateTime` format.  minutes_Var equals zero to start with.  Increments_var is user defined.  I need `item_timed_close` to increment by whatever the `Increments_var` is set to.

**EDIT**

Results I am looking for would be something like this:

User specifies a starting date of `2012-01-08 12:00:00 PM` and an increment of `10` seconds.  For each row updated, the date would look like:

```
2012-01-08 12:00:00 PM
2012-01-08 12:00:10 PM
2012-01-08 12:00:20 PM
2012-01-08 12:00:30 PM
2012-01-08 12:00:40 PM
2012-01-08 12:00:50 PM
2012-01-08 12:01:00 PM
2012-01-08 12:01:10 PM
2012-01-08 12:01:20 PM
```

The first date could even have the incremented value already added to it for all we care, so long as it increments.  I could change the initial starting date with that in mind through code.

**Update**

With Naval's suggestion, I tried a sub query.  First, I set all date fields to NULL.  Then, I run the following query:

```
        strSQL3.CommandText = "Update tblItem set item_timed_close=DATEADD(minute,((Select count(*) as Count From tblItem Where item_sale_id=@item_sale_id And item_timed_close Is NULL) * @increment),convert(datetime, @item_timed_close)),item_timed_start=convert(money, case when item_est_lo < 500 then ((convert(int,item_est_lo+25)/50)*50) when item_est_lo < 1000 then ((convert(int,item_est_lo+50)/100)*100) when item_est_lo < 3000 then ((convert(int,item_est_lo+125)/250)*250) when item_est_lo < 5000 then ((convert(int,item_est_lo+250)/500)*500) else ((convert(int,item_est_lo+12.5)/25)*25) end ) Where item_sale_id=@item_sale_id";
        strSQL3.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@item_timed_close", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "item_timed_close", DataRowVersion.Current, datetime_Var));
        strSQL3.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@item_sale_id", SqlDbType.Int, 5, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "item_sale_id", DataRowVersion.Current, itemSaleId3_Var));
        strSQL3.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@increment", SqlDbType.Int, 5, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "increment", DataRowVersion.Current, Increments_var));
```

I was hoping that I could multiply the sub query by the variable passed in, but it didn't work as expected.  It seems to multiply the `@increment` by 1 for every field.  I've run the select statement alone and it returns 471.  So I know that part works correctly.  Do I need to cast `Count` as an integer or something?

**DONE**

I finally got it.  I should have thought of this initially....  I had to change the counter variable in my update string's regular `Set` sequence.  Here is my working query.

```
 Declare @auto Int 
 Set @auto = 0 

 Update tblItem 
    set item_timed_close = DATEADD(minute, (@auto * @increment), convert(datetime, @item_timed_close))
      , item_timed_start = convert(money, 
                case when item_est_lo < 500  then ((convert(int, item_est_lo+25)/50)*50) 
                     when item_est_lo < 1000 then ((convert(int, item_est_lo+50)/100)*100) 
                     when item_est_lo < 3000 then ((convert(int, item_est_lo+125)/250)*250) 
                     when item_est_lo < 5000 then ((convert(int, item_est_lo+250)/500)*500) 
                     else ((convert(int,item_est_lo+12.5)/25)*25) end )
      , @auto = (@auto + 1) 
  Where item_sale_id=@item_sale_id
```

So I used the original example I had found, and just took out the last `Set @counter` part and put that into my update string's `set` parameters.

Comment: The query you wrote looks flawed ... is it running correctly ?

Comment: @Naval Yes, as it is, it is running correctly.  I just need it to also increment the date by the number of minutes the user specifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it.  I should have thought of this initially....  I had to change the counter variable in my update string's regular `Set` sequence.  Here is my working query.

```
 Declare @auto Int Set @auto = 0 Update tblItem set item_timed_close=DATEADD(minute,(@auto * @increment),convert(datetime, @item_timed_close)),item_timed_start=convert(money, case when item_est_lo < 500 then ((convert(int,item_est_lo+25)/50)*50) when item_est_lo < 1000 then ((convert(int,item_est_lo+50)/100)*100) when item_est_lo < 3000 then ((convert(int,item_est_lo+125)/250)*250) when item_est_lo < 5000 then ((convert(int,item_est_lo+250)/500)*500) else ((convert(int,item_est_lo+12.5)/25)*25) end ),@auto = (@auto + 1) Where item_sale_id=@item_sale_id
```

So I used the original example I had found, and just took out the last `Set @counter` part and put that into my update string's `set` parameters.

Answer (score 1):

`strSQL.Parameters.Add(` is not the place to do the incrementing logic.  According to the sample, try to work that into your update statement.  First add another parameter for `Increments_Var` and use `DATEADD` in your update statement to add it to your @item_timed_close while at the same time updating @item_timed_close to the new sum.  I would suggest starting with something simple that uses the sample and dates instead of integers, then build up from there.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would write the example with my update in a single statement because of the `@` sign thinking it's a new parameter.  I tried just putting it into my code in the way it is set up, and it does nothing at all to increment the date.

Answer (score 1):

Try This: ... i am writing a query, you convert it to your database format.

> Update TableName Set DateD = DateAdd('MI',(ID*10),'01-Jan-2011 00:00:00')

ID column is your identity field (AutoIncrement) ID*10 = multiplying it by 10 to get different datetime.

I think this will work :)

Take Care:)

Comment: But wouldn't this be static?  In other words, `ID*10` would equal the same thing for every entry?  Or do you think that ID is a table field?  In this case, ID would be a minute value specified by the user (not already in the database).

Comment: ID would be auto increment primary key ... it will be different and unique for the table

Comment: But that doesn't help in what I need to do.  Nor does the table have any auto increment field.

Comment: James .... im asking u to add an id field which is autoincrement ... what happens with auto increment is that  ... it increments by 1 for every record and hence is unique .... .... now for first record (ID=1) the query will add (1*10 =10) 10 minutes to the date field ...this will go on for all the records ... the second record will have 20 minutes added to it and so on .... got it ??

Comment: Yes, I understand what that would do.  And that is not what I want done.  I am not updating every single record in the database.  Only ones matching certain criteria.

Comment: hmmm .... do you want time to increment by 10 ... or will a varied increment work (means sometimes by 10 ...at others by 20 etc) ?

Comment: Well it's varied.  The increment is user-defined.  So it can really be anything.  But the problem is that it only applies to a certain sale.  So putting an incrementing field into the database won't help.

Comment: then Replace ID with this Query : "Select Count(*) from TableName T2 where T2.Creteria = Where Clause criteria"  ... this will generate serial no for each records and then you can multiply that by 10,20 ..etc. :)

Comment: I'll try that when I get back in the office tomorrow, but won't that be the same for each item?  The count query will be the same no matter which item it is updating in that sale, so nothing will actually increment.

Comment: no James .. it is going to be  a sub query ... so u will have different count for each record which comes in the select clause

Comment: I'm not sure I understand then.  Is this where clause supposed to be different than the one I have above?  If not, won't it just select the total number of items in the specified sale?  Because that number wouldn't change on each pass.  But, it does give me an idea now that I think about it.  And if it works, I'll mark this as the answer and post what I did.

Comment: I've updated the question with my results.  It's still not working right, though.

Comment: I finally figured it out using the original example I had found on the net with minor changes.  Thanks for the help anyway.